# Create permanent download link for file in PHP

Tags: php

My PHP script is in direcoty `/home/foo/public_html/php_script/index.php`

In this directory there is folder named images and it contains some images. How can I get the permanent download link to these images.

```
e.g http://www.example.com/~foo/php_script/images/image.gif
```

Comment: Please explain a little bit more about what you want.

Comment: I have to create a download link for the file that is placed in the folder named images. Permanent link like the ones we get from imageshack.us or from dropbox.com etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question doesn't really make sense to me. Seems to me that you shouldn't need to do anything special, just link to your pictures... So use that URL example you gave, that should work already.

Since you're asking this question, I suppose you've tried that already? What web server are you using?

In your index.php, I'd just roll with something along the lines of...

```
<?php>
    echo "<img src=\"/~foo/php_script/images/image.gif\" />";
</php>
```

But perhaps I'm being a newb and really missing the question...?

Comment: I dont know what I was thinking while I asked this question. Thanks man. Now I am feeling DUMB,lolzzz

Comment: Heh, no worries man. I'm just glad I wasn't somehow missing a far deeper meaning. Glad you're back on track. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Have a function doing this

```
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
readfile($filename);
```

and call this function upon clicking the download link

see here for readfile info

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: I know about, but this is not what I am looking, I want link like this http://www.blogshopcity.com/attachments/ladies-fashion-clothing/19757d1287970665-example-how-our-sticky-thread-our-sponsor-thread-looks-like-600px-example.svg.png

Comment: that should work by default, do you have read permissions for all users for the images folder